# How can I tell if a Realm has been successfully updated?

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I'm new to using Realm databases with react-native and while the documentation/api generally makes things seem clear enough (which is very much appreciated btw), I don't see anywhere in the api that when I try to modify (create, update, delete) a db table in a Realm I can add a method to track success or failure **and respond in kind**. Is it there and I just don't see it or is there a way that I'm expected to handle this apart from adding a callback as an argument?

Answer (score 3):

Failures in Realm will result in exceptions being throw, so you can handle failures by using try/catch blocks. `Realm.create` and `Realm.delete` should only throw if you have a logic error in your code. `Realm.write` could throw if there is an error when trying to write the db to disk.

You could easily create your own wrapper so that you could pass in a callback for success/error rather than having to write a try/catch block for every write:

```
function writeWithError(realm, writeCallback, errorCallback) {
    try {
        realm.write(writeCallback);
        errorCallback(undefined);
    }
    catch(e) {
        errorCallback(e);
    }
}
```

The example calls the error callback with `undefined` on success, or with the error if an error was thrown. You could also try using `Object.defineProperty` to attach this to the `Realm` object so you can call it as a member function.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I don't think that no error/exception being caught is really a good indicator of success. Also, what my initial question asked was about being able to "track success or failure and respond in kind" and I supposed I'd want to put some emphasis on "respond in kind." Do you know if there is any way to include a callback function or something akin to a callback function?

Comment: I changed my answer with an example of how you could wrap writes to support error callbacks.

Comment: I appreciate your response and am only going to press further on this because it seems that you've answered a number of other Realm questions and I'm thinking it's probably that you work for Realm. If I'm mistaken please excuse my pushiness. 
The main issue I'm having with the additional try/catch statement is that it includes "writeCallback" as an argument for realm.write, but realm.write is already expecting a function call here as per the spec:
realm.write(() => {
  realm.create('Car', {make: 'Honda', model: 'Accord', drive: 'awd'});
});

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Since writes are synchronous, we don't need a callback to let us know if the write was successful. After the function passed to `Realm.write` is run, all of the changes made inside of it are written to the database, and if an error occurs at any time, then an exception will be thrown and all changes made inside that function will be discarded. Any exceptions thrown within `writeCallback` are propagated by write so you can catch everything using a single try/catch.